# Using "this" as an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments, this

I have an onclick function to navigate from one "page" to another (it's not actually navigating, just imitates it):

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.home').css('display','none');
    var newPage = $('.'+this.id);
    goTo(newPage);
});
```

goTo simplified for reference:

```
function goTo(page){
 $(page).css('display', 'block');
}
```

This works perfectly fine. All of the navigation buttons have the class of button, and also an ID that matches the class name of the different "pages". Click #page1, display .page1, etc.

My problem is now I'm having to rewrite my code to do the same thing for other elements - trying to rewrite this with arguments doesn't work for this in particular.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
function goToPage(link, destination){
 link.click(function(){
  $('.home').css('display','none');
  goTo(destination);
 }
}
```

and calling it as:

```
goToPage($('#page1'), $('.page1'));
```

works fine, however:

```
goToPage($('.button'), $('.'+this.id));
```

doesn't.

I suppose I'm misunderstanding how "this" is working in this context. I thought it would only determine what "this" is when the argument is called.

So my question is: can "this" be used as an argument in this way, am I slightly off with the logic or am I a complete idiot?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hek0ptca/13/

Comment: Could you show us the markup?

Comment: Where are you calling `goToPage($('.button'), $('.'+this.id))` from, as `this` will be in the context of the surrounding closure. You need to post the code that shows us making the `goToPage(...)` call.

Comment: `goToPage(this, '.'+this.id);`

Comment: Is the `goToPage` call being assigned by an event handler?

Comment: is your **this** can hold element or not

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hek0ptca/13/ Here's a fiddle. I hope that answers most of your questions. It's not assigned by an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly answer your question, no, `this` cannot be used as an argument in this case because it points to nothing.

```
goToPage($('.button'), $('.'+this.id));
```

In this context, `this` points to "undefined". Try running `console.log(this.id);`at the same scope of the code mentioned above and check your browser's console. It returns "undefined".

A good way to think about `this` is that you need something for it to reference. Scope matters. If there is nothing for this to reference, you will always get "undefined" as a value. Typically `this` is used inside a function where an object has already been referenced, for example, inside your event handler:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#home').css('display', 'none');
    goTo($('.'+this.id));
});
```

This will work in this case because `this` will refer back to the object that is being operated on, the .button class.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did start to understand this more shortly after posting. I am still stumped however, if I were to call this as 

$('.button').click(function(){
 goToPage($(this), $('.'+this.id));
});

It would work, but I'd have to double click (understandably - once to call the function, and another time for the function). Do you know of a way to invoke this function for that object, without an event?

Comment: The reason you have to double click is because in the fiddle you provided, JQuery registers the first click event from  `$('.button').click(function(){ goToPage($(this), $('.'+this.id)); }); ` but then you have another click event in the goToPage() function.


And yes, you can force events using the .trigger() function. Read here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Or you can just call the function and pass the ID of the element you are trying to perform an operation on like
`goToPage('#page1', ...);`